# Check if parent fragment implements an interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm using nested fragments that communicate via interfaces. In the past, where I had the following fragment nested in an activity, I did something like this:

**ChildFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        _mOnImageAvailableListener = (OnImageAvailableListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()+" must implement onImageAvailable");
    }
}
```

But, if **ChildFragment.java** is nested inside **ParentFragment.java**, how can I ensure **ParentFragment.java** implements `OnImageAvailableListener` ?

Answer (score 3):

In ParentFragment you should use `getChildFragmentManager()` and not `getFragmentManager()` or `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Than in ChildFragment you can do this

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(getParentFragment() instanceof OnImageAvailableListener) {
        // cast and save it to instance variable..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `getParentFragment()`. Something like this:

```
if (getParentFragment() instanceOf OnImageAvailableListener){
//do something
} else {
//throw an exception
}
```

Comment: `getParentFragment()` returns `null`

Comment: Move it to the `onActivityCreated()` method or `onViewCreated( )`

Comment: Still returning `null`

Comment: hmn, maybe the `getParent()`works, I dont know how your code works.

Comment: `getParent()` isn't a thing. I'm using `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` if that helps

Comment: I checked the documentation, and according the method it returns the parent Fragment containing this Fragment.  If this Fragment is attached directly to an Activity, returns null. 
Here, `getParentFragment( )` works well. Maybe your fragment is attached directly to and activity or something else.

Comment: Hm, so in `fragment_parent.xml`, I have `<fragment android:name="ChildFragment"...` does that count as attaching a child fragment to the parent or do I have to do something else ?

Answer (score 1):

ChildFragment.java directly used in your activity like callback.

Think in your activity anywhere put this code like button click ..

```
     FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
     ChildFragment childFragment= new ChildFragment();
     childFragment.show(fm, "Select Position");
```

In your ChildFragment.java create interface and attach activity look.

```
private InterfaceName faceName;

public interface InterfaceName {
    void setPosition(int position);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Activity activity;
    if (context instanceof Activity) {
        activity = (Activity) context;
        try {
            faceName= (InterfaceName ) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement Listener");
        }
    }
}
```

And finally callback in your fragments.

```
faceName.setPosition(position, INDEX);
```

Implements ChildFragment.InterfaceName in your activity and you get it position.

```
 @Override
public void setPosition(int position) {

 }
```